# Is it possible to put a subquery inside the FROM statement in my HQL Querys?

Tags: hql

Here is my query.

```
SELECT letter 
FROM 
Letter AS letter,
(evaluateDisplayName) AS displayName
WHERE
letter.id =: someID
AND displayName =: someDisplayName
// AND etc etc...
```

The Subquery in this part:

```
(Do some subquery here) AS displayName
```

I don't know how to form. But the logic is something like this:

```
private String evaluateDisplayName(Letter letter) {
        def username = letter?.sender?.username
        def lastName = letter?.sender?.lastName
        def emailAddress = letter?.sender?.emailAddress

        return username ?: lastName ?: emailAddress
    }
```

How to turn this into a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery, the logic of `evaluateDisplayName` seems to be the same of the `coalesce` function: return the first not null value. Try with this:

```
SELECT letter 
FROM 
Letter AS letter LEFT JOIN letter.sender AS sender
WHERE
letter.id = :someID
AND COALESCE(sender.username, sender.lastName, sender.emailAddress) = :someDisplayName
// AND etc etc...
```